# DNS config to handle email for third party subdomain

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, delegation

Our customers host their own email (e.g. company.com), but need our service to handle email addressed to a specific subdomain (e.g. sub.company.com)

We'd like to control DNS for their subdomain, allowing us to have IP address flexibility in providing this service.

How would customers delegate DNS subdomain control to us, and would this work for email MX lookups to this subdomain hosted by our servers?

Any gotchas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

They create `NS` records for the subdomain in question, pointed at your DNS servers, and then you configure authoritative DNS zones on those servers for that delegation.

Once the above is in place, yes, `MX` queries and all others will function as expected in this delegated subdomain.